# Consuming WCF service in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.forms

I am wishing to connect to a WCF service (running on a Windows PC) via Xamarin Form based on [this sample code](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WebServices/TodoWCF).
I successfully managed to find and create the Connected Service pointing to the WCF. and I followed the same approach that I earlier used in the UWP environment.

But once I call any of the methods exposed in the service I get this exception in the Android environment.
`The method or operation is not implemented`

I don't use **PCL** style but .net way.

[image]

here is the stack trace of the exception.

````
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelFactory[TChannel] () [0x00007] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/BindingContext.cs:149 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingElement.BuildChannelFactory[TChannel] (System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext context) [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/BindingElement.cs:52 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement.BuildChannelFactory[TChannel] (System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext context) [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement.cs:94 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelFactory[TChannel] () [0x00007] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/BindingContext.cs:149 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding.BuildChannelFactory[TChannel] (System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection parameters) [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/Binding.cs:133 
  at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.CreateFactory () [0x000be] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ChannelFactory.cs:202 
  at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.OnOpening () [0x00006] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ChannelFactory.cs:383 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ProcessOpening () [0x00017] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/CommunicationObject.cs:276 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open (System.TimeSpan timeout) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/CommunicationObject.cs:169 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/CommunicationObject.cs:164 
  at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.EnsureOpened () [0x0004c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ChannelFactory.cs:297 
  at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[TChannel].CreateChannel () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ChannelFactory_1.cs:108 
  at System.ServiceModel.DuplexClientBase`1[TChannel].CreateChannel () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/DuplexClientBase.cs:123 
  at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[TChannel].get_InnerChannel () [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientBase.cs:186 
  at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[TChannel].get_Channel () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientBase.cs:192 
  at AppMobileService.AppMobileCommandHandlerClientBase.SubscribeAsync (System.String name, AppMobileService.AppMobileConnectionType connectionType) [0x00001] in C:\Users\adm\Desktop\AppMobilePortable\AppMobilePortable\AppMobilePortable\Connected Services\AppMobileService\Reference.cs:945 
  at PortableAppMobile.Services.AppMobileClientService.Connect () [0x00024] in C:\Users\adm\Desktop\AppMobilePortable\AppMobilePortable\AppMobilePortable\Service\AppMobileClientService.cs:136  ```
````

Comment: there is very little we can do to help you if you do not show us the actual code you are using.  Please read [ask] before posting

Comment: @Jason thank you for your reply. My question was actually a bit more general and pointing to the possibility/principal of that. I am not very sure if Xamarin.Forms 5 has [.Net 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five) limitations or not.

Comment: @Reza Check the liminations in the document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/wcf If it is possible, please provide more details. According to official document, Xamarin support WCF.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I include more detail on the caught exception. I hope it helps. BTW, I used exactly the same code that I am using in UWP and it is working. I don't use PCL approach can it be the problem?

Comment: In uwp,  you should be able to test the application on a PC with no additional configuration. Testing Android and iOS clients may require the additional steps in this section. Please check the link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services